# JavaFX java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException when launching textbook file

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, runtime-error

Ive brought my textbook example into eclipse in a new JavaFX project. Code, error and other screenshots can be found at the bottom. What follows is a list of things ive tried:

I have --module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-18.0.1\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml in my run configurations.

I have added all of the .jars into a library titled "JAVAFX" that is in the build path

I have gone into that library and added the location of src.zip as well as downloaded the javadocs from the website and added those locations as well.

I do not know what else to do, please help.

Code:

**DrawLines.java:**

```
package application;
    
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DrawLines extends Application {
   @Override
   public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
      // loads DrawLines.fxml and configures the DrawLinesController
      Parent root = 
         FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Drawlines.fxml"));

      Scene scene = new Scene(root); // attach scene graph to scene
      stage.setTitle("Draw Lines"); // displayed in window's title bar
      stage.setScene(scene); // attach scene to stage
      stage.show(); // display the stage
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      launch(args); // create a DrawLines object and call its start method
   }
}
```

**DrawLinesController.java**

```
 package application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;

public class DrawLinesController {

    @FXML
    private Canvas canvas;

    @FXML
    void drawLinesButtonPressed(ActionEvent event) {
        
    GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

    gc.strokeLine(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());


    gc.strokeLine( canvas.getWidth(), 0,0, canvas.getHeight());
    }
}
```

Drawlines.FXML

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ToolBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>


<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/18" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="DrawLinesController">
   <top>
      <ToolBar prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <items>
          <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="DrawLines" />
        </items>
      </ToolBar>
   </top>
   <center>
      <Canvas fx:id="canvas" height="300.0" width="300.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Error:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:119)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:465)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1081)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:901)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/Xxmoz/OneDrive/Documents/git-hub-repos/Eclipse%20Projects/Drawlines/bin/application/Drawlines.fxml:9

    at javafx.fxml@18.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml@18.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:933)
    at javafx.fxml@18.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:981)
    at javafx.fxml@18.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:230)
    at javafx.fxml@18.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:755)
    at javafx.fxml@18.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2808)
    at javafx.fxml@18.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2634)
    at javafx.fxml@18.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    at javafx.fxml@18.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3331)
    at javafx.fxml@18.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3287)
    at javafx.fxml@18.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3255)
    at javafx.fxml@18.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3227)
    at javafx.fxml@18.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3203)
    at javafx.fxml@18.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3196)
    at application.DrawLines.start(DrawLines.java:14)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:847)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:484)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:457)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: DrawLinesController
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at javafx.fxml@18.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:931)
    ... 22 more
Exception running application application.DrawLines
```

Comment: "added the location of src.zip as well as downloaded the javadocs from the website and added those locations as well." -> that may assist with IDE support (e.g. navigating to documentation or source from the IDE), but it will not affect runtime errors as those files are not used at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fx:controller` reference needs to be a fully qualified name (including the package).

Change:

```
fx:controller="DrawLinesController"
```

to:

```
fx:controller="application.DrawLinesController"
```

Comment: ....welp this week on "Man, I might be an idiot"

I appreciate the help.